# Decision problem for the splitting type of rank 2 bundle from the given exact sequence

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, exact-sequence

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a rank 2 vector bundle over some algebraic variety.

After restrict to the given line $L\cong\mathbb{P}^1$, it fits into an exact sequecne
$$
0 \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_L(-2)\rightarrow \mathcal{F}|L \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_L\oplus\mathcal{O}_q\rightarrow 0,
$$
where $q$ denotes a point over $L$. Then for compute the splitting type of $\mathcal{F}|L$,

1. The first chern class. Since $c_1(\mathcal{O}_L(-2))=-2$ and $c_1(\mathcal{O}_L\oplus\mathcal{O}_q)=1,$

I have $c_1(\mathcal{F}|L)=-1$ and so I guess $$\mathcal{F}|L\cong\mathcal{O}_L(-2)\oplus\mathcal{O}_L(1)$$ or $$\mathcal{F}|L\cong\mathcal{O}_L(-1)\oplus\mathcal{O}_L.$$

2. At that time, I want to show that the one of them is actually cannot fits into above exact sequnce,
   to conclude what is the splitting type of $\mathcal{F}|L$ is.

Can I get your help? Thank you.

Comment: If $q$ is a reduced point, then I would assume you want to twist to get $0\to\mathcal O_L(-1)\to(\mathcal F|L)(1)\to\mathcal O_L(1)\oplus\mathcal O_q\to 0$, where we are using the general fact that skyscraper sheaves of points on curves don't change under twisting by a line bundle. Now it would appear that this is the direct sum of the sequences $0\to\mathcal O_L(-1)\to\mathcal O_L\to\mathcal O_q\to 0$ and what I will write as $0\to 0\to\mathcal O_L(1)\to\mathcal O_L(1)\to 0$ to make the grading clear. So I conclude $\mathcal F|L\cong\mathcal O\oplus\mathcal O(-1)$ after twisting back down...

Comment: ...But I've always found this kind of argument somewhat tricky, so don't take my word as gospel. As for why the first splitting *doesn't* work: in this situation the injective map is (I think, because again homological stuff tends to throw me off) the inclusion of the first summand, so the sequence splits and we get an isomorphism $\mathcal O_L(1) \cong \mathcal O_L \oplus \mathcal O_q$ which is obviously absurd since the right hand side is not locally free.

Comment: @TabesBridges Thank you for your comment!! It is sufficient to me now. If you don't mind, couldn't you recommend some textbook or lecture(note) using the technic like this to compute splitting types? Again, I appreciate your kind and clear answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not something I've ever found really written up, and it was somewhat a matter of luck that I was able to figure this out. It comes up organically in books like Olivier Debarre's *Higher Dimensional Algebraic Geometry* that deal with rational curves on varieties, but such authors tend to assume you have at least some idea of what you're doing already. I would suggest Googling the phrase "splitting type" (along with some more algebro-geometric keywords if needed to filter out non-math results) and seeing if you find some papers that look approachable...

Comment: ...Actually, you could look at Eisenbud-Harris' *3264 & All That*. Somewhere in that book they discuss the locus of jumping lines for a vector bundles $\mathcal E$ on $\mathbb P^2$ (There is a dense open subset $U \subset\mathbb P^{2\vee}$ parametrizing lines $L \subset \mathbb P^2$ for which the splitting type $\mathcal E|_L$ is constant; lines parametrized by the complement of $U$ are called **jumping lines** since the splitting type *jumps* (a term which I want to say is justified because in general the cohomology of the restricted bundle jumps as well)).

Comment: @TabesBridges I appreciate your advice. Thank you so much.